# Do we Visualize Big Data

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science, altair

I began to fall in love with a Python Visualization library called Altair, and i use it with every small data science project that ive done.

Now, in terms of Industry use cases, **Does it make sense to visualize Big Data** or should we just take a random sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, if you're trying to visualize data with tens of thousands of rows or more, Altair is probably not the right tool. But there are efforts in progress to add support for larger datasets in the vega ecosystem; see https://github.com/vega/scalable-vega.